# numpy ndarray throw exception when truncating string

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm having an `ndarray` of ascii strings of different lengths. Until now I used `dtype=object` for this. However profiling showed that this is actually a bottleneck in my program. Using `dtype=np.string_` is faster, however  it has the downside that it silently truncates the set values. Since this is a perfect recipe for hard to find bugs I wonder if there is a possibility to either rescale (I know that this could be costly in case of entire reallocation) the array or raise an Exception in case of truncation?

I couldn't change `ndarray.__setitem__` since its an read-only attribute. Here is some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
import numpy as np


def Foo(vec):
    vec[1] = 'FAIL'

    print('{:6s}: {}'.format(str(vec.dtype), vec))


VALUES = ['OK', 'OK', 'OK']

Foo(np.array(VALUES, dtype=object)) # Slow but it works
Foo(np.array(VALUES, dtype=np.string_)) # Fast but may fail silently
```

Resulting in:

```
object: ['OK' 'FAIL' 'OK']
|S2   : [b'OK' b'FA' b'OK']
```

Comment: *"...raise an Exception in case of truncation?"*  It would be nice if setting some flag enabled this behavior, perhaps something similar to how `numpy.seterr()` controls the handling of floating point errors.  I've never seen such a flag, but as an enhancement request for numpy, I'd give it a +1.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. I agree, it could also be a warning or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a non-flexible solution by inheriting from `ndarray`. I will not accept this answer till Friday maybe somebody comes up with something better. It fulfills its duties, even on views (eg. StringArray(...)[1:4])

```
import numpy as np

class StringArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        field_length = max(map(len, val))
        # Could also be <U for unicode
        vec = super().__new__(cls, len(val), dtype='|S' + str(field_length))
        vec[:] = val[:]
        return vec

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if isinstance(val, (list, tuple, nd.array)):
            if max(map(len, val)) > self.dtype.itemsize:
                raise ValueError('Itemsize too big')
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            if len(val) > self.dtype.itemsize:
                raise ValueError('Itemsize too big')
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown type')
        super().__setitem__(key, val)


val = StringArray(['a', 'ab', 'abc'])
print(val)
val[0] = 'xy'
print(val)
try:
    val[0] = 'xyze'
except ValueError:
    print('Catch')

try:
    val[1:2] = ['xyze', 'sd']
except ValueError:
    print('Catch')
```

produces:

```
[b'a' b'ab' b'abc']
[b'xy' b'ab' b'abc']
Catch
Catch
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see I can explain what's going on

```
In [32]: ll=['one','two','three']
In [33]: a1=np.array(ll,dtype=object)
In [34]: a1
Out[34]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)
In [35]: a1[1]='eleven'
In [36]: a1
Out[36]: array(['one', 'eleven', 'three'], dtype=object)
```

`a1` just like `ll` consists of pointers - pointers to strings that reside elsewhere in memory.  I can change any of those pointers, just as I could in a list.  In most ways `a1` behaves just like a list - except that it is possible to reshape, and do some other basic `array` things.

```
In [37]: a1.reshape(3,1)
Out[37]: 
array([['one'],
       ['eleven'],
       ['three']], dtype=object)
```

But if I make a `string` array

```
In [38]: a2=np.array(ll)
In [39]: a2
Out[39]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U5')
In [42]: a1.itemsize
Out[42]: 4
In [43]: a2.itemsize
Out[43]: 20
```

the values are stored in the array's data buffer.  Here it made an array with 5 unicode characters per element (Python3) (5*4 bytes each).

Now if I replace an element of `a2` I can get truncation

```
In [44]: a2[1]='eleven'
In [45]: a2
Out[45]: 
array(['one', 'eleve', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

because only 5 of the characters of the new value fit in the allocated space.

So there's a trade off - faster access speed because the bytes are stored in a fixed, known size array, but you can't store bigger things.

You could allocate more space per element:

```
In [46]: a3=np.array(ll,dtype='|U10')
In [47]: a3
Out[47]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U10')
In [48]: a3[1]='eleven'
In [49]: a3
Out[49]: 
array(['one', 'eleven', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

`genfromtxt` is a common tool for creating arrays with string dtypes.  That waits until it has read all the file before setting the string length (at least if using `dtype=None`). And the string fields are often part of a multi-field structured array.   The string fields are usually labels or ids, not something you commonly change.

I can imagine writing a function that would check string length against the dtype and raise an error if the truncation would happen.  But that's going to slow down the action.

```
def foo(A, i, astr):
    if A.itemsize/4<len(astr):
        raise ValueError('too long str')
    A[i] = astr

In [69]: foo(a2,1,'four')
In [70]: a2
Out[70]: 
array(['one', 'four', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U5')
In [72]: foo(a2,1,'eleven')
...
ValueError: too long str
```

but is it worth the extra work?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This elaborates on the cause, but unfortunately doesn't give me a solution to my problem. I played around a bit and found an solution of sorts, not very flexible I'm afraid though.

Comment: What kind of flexibility do you need?  What are you doing with these string arrays after construction?  It can be tricky to ensure that subclassing is preserved when passing through various `numpy` functions.  Note for example that `np.array` has `subok` parameter.

Comment: I don't know as of this moment. At the moment you can think of it as a table which is read (>95% the times) and somethimes written to. However future use might differ. Which is also somethings that scares my about subclassing/constructing the container myself instead of the provided factory function. I'd hate to introduce some hard to track bugs which will only surface once I forgot what I did half a year ago.

Comment: A table as in a 2d layout out of strings?